# How to use linestyle=dashed in the following case?

Tags: pstricks, pst-electricfield

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1.25cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(4,3.5)
\def\figure{\begin{pspicture*}(-4.5,-3)(4.5,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=green!20](-4.5,-3)(4.5,3)
\psLineSegments[arrowsize=.15cm]{->}(-2,0)(-1,0)(-2,0)(-2.75,0)(2,0)(1,0)(2,0)(2.75,0)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,griddots=10]
\psElectricfield[Q={[1 -2 0][1 2 0]},N=21,Pas=0.0155]
\foreach \n in {6,7,8,9,11.5,20}{
\psEquipotential[Q={[1 -2 0][1 2 0]},Vmin=\n,Vmax=\n](-5,-5)(5,5)}
\psline(0,-2.5)(0,2.5)
\psline(0,0.2)(.2,.2)(.2,0)
\psLineSegments[arrowsize=1.5mm]{->}(0,0)(0,0.75)(0,0)(0,1.5)(0,0)(0,-0.75)(0,0)(0,-1.5)
\psset{linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid}
\pscircle[fillcolor=white](-2.05,0){2mm}
\pscircle[fillcolor=white](2,0){2mm}
\pscircle*(-2,0){1.1mm}
\pscircle*(2,0){1.1mm}
\uput{.6pt}[135](-2,0){\tiny \pscirclebox*[framesep=0pt]{$+Q$}}
\uput{.6pt}[45](2,0){\tiny \pscirclebox*[framesep=0pt]{$+Q$}}
\end{pspicture*}}
%%%
\rput[bl](-5,-3){\figure}
\psline{->}(-1.8,3)(-2,2.5)(-1.6,2.1)
\uput[90](-1.8,3){L\'{i}nea de fuerza}
\psline{->}(1.9,3.3)(1.4,3)(1.3,2.3)
\uput{2pt}[80](1.9,3.3){Superficie equipotencial}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to use linestyle=dashed as a optional argument of \psEquipotential but it does not work. It means the result of it as the following:

[image]

Help! ...

Ađitional:

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5.5,-5.5)(5.5,5.5)
\psset{unit=1.25cm}
\def\figure{\begin{pspicture*}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psframe*[linecolor=green!20](-4,-4)(4,4)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,griddots=10]
\psElectricfield[Q={[1 -2 0][-1 2 0]},linecolor=red,N=21,Pas=0.0115]

\foreach \n in {0,1,2,3,8,19}{
    \psEquipotential[Q={[1 -2 0][-1 2 0]},Vmin=-\n,Vmax=-\n](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psEquipotential[Q={[1 -2 0][-1 2 0]},Vmin=\n,Vmax=\n](-5,-5)(5,5)
}
{\psset{linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid}
\pscircle[fillcolor=white](-2.05,0){2mm}
\pscircle[fillcolor=white](1.98,0){2mm}
\pscircle*(2,0){1.1mm}}
\pscircle(-2,0){1.1mm}
\uput{.6pt}[135](-2,0){\tiny \pscirclebox*[framesep=0pt]{$+Q$}}
\uput{.6pt}[45](2,0){\tiny \pscirclebox*[framesep=0pt]{$-Q$}}
\end{pspicture*}}

\rput[bl](-4,-4){\figure}
\psline{->}(-.8,4)(-1,3.8)(-.5,3.4)
\uput[90](-.8,4){L\'{i}nea de fuerza}
\psline{->}(-1,-4.2)(-1.7,-3.75)(-1.8,-3.2)
\uput{2pt}[-90](-1,-4.2){Superficie equipotencial}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is not possible, the calculated equipotential lines are not defined as a continoues curve.

Comment: So, two circles with linestyle=dashed are wrong!!

Comment: that are no circles!

Comment: See edited question. The problem with two " circles ", I don't know its solution....:-(

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Only very near to the charges the lines are circles. In general the equipotential lines are described by an implicit defined function. This makes it difficult to get a continious curce.

Comment: Please see new example. How to \psEquipotential is only used one time?? :-)

Comment: You can only change the color of the equipotential lines.

Comment: I do not understand your "comment". :-). I want to ask  Can \psEquipotential  be only used one time?...

Comment: If you mean "only for _one_ curve" then the answer is no